# missing mysqli extension for PHP, required by WordPress

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu

I am facing this when i go to localhost

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
>
> Please check that the mysqli PHP extension is installed and enabled.
>
> If you are unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress support forums.

I have followed and each and every step [from here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress)

Kindly tell me the appropriate solution i could not find any

Answer (score 0):

looks like you may have missed installing the mysql extension for PHP.

The below steps should get you going. Change php-mysql to the correct name if you installed a specific version of PHP, ie. php8.2-mysql, if you installed PHP v8.2.

1. sudo apt install php-mysql
2. Confirm the extension is enabled in your php.ini file. Look for extension=mysqli and ensure it is uncommented (no semicolon at the beginning).
3. Restart your web server (e.g., Apache or Nginx) to apply the changes.